# FacebookSDK returns null birthdaty and location in Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm working on Android project to fetch simple data from facebook app, so I'm using facebookSDK with this code:

```
private void FetchFacebookData()
{
    try
    {
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("user_birthday");
        permissions.add("user_location");
        permissions.add("email");

          // start Facebook Login           
          Session.openActiveSession(this, true, permissions, new Session.StatusCallback()
          {
            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {

                if (session.isOpened()) 
                {
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {
                          // callback after Graph API response with user object
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                          {
                              if (user != null) 
                              {
                                  try
                                  {
                                      JSONObject json=user.getInnerJSONObject();
                                      String UserID=json.getString("id");
                                      String FirstName=json.getString("first_name");
                                      String LastName=json.getString("last_name");
                                      String Gender=json.getString("gender");
                                      String Email=json.getString("email"); 
                                      String UserBirthday = user.getLocation()+"";
                                      String Location=user.getLocation()+"";

                                      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                                      sb.append("User ID: " + UserID + "\n");
                                      sb.append("First Name: " + FirstName + "\n");
                                      sb.append("Last Name: " + LastName + "\n");
                                      sb.append("Gender: " + Gender + "\n");
                                      sb.append("Email: " + Email + "\n");
                                      sb.append("User Birthday: " + UserBirthday + "\n");
                                      sb.append("Location: " + Location + "\n");

                                      tv.setText(sb.toString());
                                  }
                                  catch (Exception e)
                                  { 

                                  }

                              }
                          }                       
                    }).executeAsync();
                }

            }
          });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Error1", ex.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    try
    {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Error2", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

If I log in to the facebook app by the same account that I created the app on facebook, it fetches birthday and location information. however, if I log in using any other facebook account it fetched null.

Comment: i dont know about the birthday field, but keep in mind that an user is not obligated to share the location on facebook: you ask for it, but that information doesnt have to be there

Comment: Sure, the user not obligate to share his info, but even if the user set his birthday setting is public, the above code returns it null :)